# Excel form changes date to US format

Tags: excel, date, textbox

How can I prevent a textbox on an Excel Form from reformatting dates into US format?
I have a form in Excel which contains a textbox. The textbox has a cell on the worksheet as it's control source. Eg `Settings!B9`
The contents of the referenced cell (Settings!B9) is a date formatted in UK format. However when the form is displayed it is reformatting the date into US format. This is not expected by the user and it is not always clear to the user that it is doing this which could lead to some disasterous consequences. I can't see any properties of the textbox which will allow me to control the date format and the date format of the cell is set correctly to *dd/mm/yyyy. As the reformatting is done behind the scenes I can't even see how I could alter this using VBA as it would need to interrupt the binding between the textbox and the referenced cell somehow.

Comment: Plus one for the good question, but I'm not sure you can. Can't you allow direct editing on the worksheet? Make the cell *look* like a text box.

Comment: @Bathsheba The user can edit the worksheet but I am trying to make it easier for them by using a form. There are lots of other settings on the form including comboboxes with VBA code etc so unfortunately it's not that straightforward. I find it hard to believe there isn't a way of doing this so posted the question here as nobody else seems to have asked this exact question before; although there are plenty of questions about changing date formats in VBA code! Hopefully someone knows a way or at least this question will stand as testament to the fact you can't. P.S. thanks for the compliment.

Comment: @AxelRichter that doesn't agree with my testing:
I input into the cell: 10/03/2015
Cell shows: 10/03/2015
Formula bar shows: 10/03/2015
Textbox shows: 3/10/2015
Locale: UK
Cell Format: *dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: You can do that with VBA code.  For example, with a simple text box, linked to cell A1, you could put this in the TextboxChange Event code:  ` With TextBox21
        .Value = Format(.Value, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
    End With`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I got all excited then. However in testing I have found that when you tab out of the field it actually changes it to the wrong date! So I entered 10-Mar-2015 and when I tab out of the field it changes to 03-Oct-2015.

Comment: I cannot help further with the information you have provided.  Please review the HELP pages for information on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and how to [provide an example of your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, (in the form..) you may just separate the day, month, and year input in the excel form.

Then use `=date(year(A1),month(A2),day(A3))` to 'recombine them as a valid date values.